# SimpleDB library with joins in Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

Is there a Ruby library for Amazon's SimpleDB that can generate joins from Ruby classes? For example, if you define Ruby classes for Game and Ball, and each Game has one Ball, code should be generated that queries for the appropriate Ball given an instance of Game, much in the way ActiveRecord works.

[RightAWS](http://rightaws.rubyforge.org/) is the most popular Ruby AWS library I can find, but it doesn't handle this. If there's no library to do it is everyone just doing this manually, or is there an elegant way to generate the right queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their have been server attempts to create something like this that I am aware of, but probably the best supported solution is to use [datamapper](http://datamapper.org/) with one of the available sdb adapters.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [SimpleRecord](http://github.com/appoxy/simple_record/) and it's belongs_to relationship mapping.

Comment: That link appears to be dead.